# Run a function after django server has started

Tags: django, django-3

I want to run a function after django server has started. Now, that function should run after all the views and URLs are initialized because the function might make requests to one of the registered routes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116948/django-initialization

Comment: This won't work, as at that point the views and URLs are not initialized. So the function won't be able to make request to the route.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to call `scrape()` function from `task.py`.

You can call the function in `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .task import scrape

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

scrape()
```

You can also use threading here if you encounter any problem.